# Double-entry table and export to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm having some troubles with this table:

```
import csv

with open('chill.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
for s in range(0,70,5):
    for t in range(-25,10,5):
        print 13.127 + 0.6215*t-11.362*s**0.16+0.396*t*s**0.16, '\t',
    print
writer.writerow([13.127 + 0.6215*t-11.362*s**0.16+0.396*t*s**0.16])
```

The problem is that the inputs of the rows and columns (`s` and `t`) are directly took and elaborated into the `print` statement, but I need to display in both rows and columns the value from which these results derive. Moreover, I've tried to export the table to a .csv file using the usual commands, but Python gives me back a runtime error:
`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. How can I solve these two issues?

Btw, I'm working with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs to be *inside* the with block:

```
with open('chill.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for s in range(0,70,5):
        for t in range(-25,10,5):
            print 13.127 + 0.6215*t-11.362*s**0.16+0.396*t*s**0.16, '\t',
        print
    writer.writerow([13.127 + 0.6215*t-11.362*s**0.16+0.396*t*s**0.16])
```

Once you leave the body of the `with` statement the file is closed so  `writer.writerow` is going to fail with the error you see.

If you want all the data in one row and printed:

```
with open('chill.csv', 'wb') as f:
    import csv
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    data = ([str(13.127 + 0.6215 * t - 11.362 * s ** 0.16 + 0.396 * t * s ** 0.16)
                 for t in range(-25, 10, 5)]
                     for s in range(0, 70, 5))
    for row in data:
        print("\t".join(row))
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But how can I display initial values on both rows and columns, in the shell and on the CSV?

Comment: If you want both to print  to the screen and write to the csv just add a writerow wherever you have a print or are you talking about what is in the file already?

Comment: I've checked the file... Using the code above only stores the last computed value in the very first cell, so I've put the `writer.writerow` inside the `for` cycle, but now prints the whole table in a single column...

Comment: Yes because I left the writerow outside the loop as per your own code, if you want it to write every time indent it inside the loop. writerow adds a new row each time, if you only write one value each time what would you expect to see? Do you want  a single row just?

Comment: but how can I export the table in a way that it looks like the output in the shell?

Comment: Sorry Padraic, I meant that the table should be `s*t`, i.e. the same size used as input, not that the whole data should be in a single row

Comment: @james42, it  has 7 columns and 14 rows tab delimited

Comment: Yes, exactly... How can this stuff be fixed?

Comment: But in this case, different values are not separated with a comma... Each row is written in a single cell

Comment: They are tab delimited which is what your code is doing, where are you adding a comma? If you want them comma delimited then use a commas not a tab character. If you want tab in the output and comma in the file doing the joining in the for loop and call `writer.writerow` on each row

Comment: @james42, it now tab delimits to the shell and comma separated in the file, if that is not it then I have no idea what you actually want

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now everything is fine!

Comment: Good, glad we got there as I was out of ideas ;)